# Busy Beaver non-computability proof by contradiction

Tags: turing-machines, busy-beaver

When proving the non-computability of the Busy Beaver function by contradiction, people create machines that are able to calculate the Busy Beaver function, BB(n), and also write more than 1s than BB(k), where k is the number of states of such machines.

[Proof link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#Proof_for_uncomputability_of_S(n)_and_%CE%A3(n))

I would like to know why this is proof that BB(n) is non-computable. In my view, this proves that BB(n) is not an upper bound for the number of 1's a finite Turing machine can write; or it also shows that these proposed machines are impossible to build.

I see that in this proofs the machine that calculates BB(n) is actually missing the calculation, since the machines score more than BB(k).

Where is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Note that $BB(n)$ is *by definition* an upper bound on the number of 1s a halting TM with $n$ states can print, so if we find that our TM has $k$ states and can print more than $BB(k)$ 1s and halt, that is a contradiction with the definition of $BB(k)$. So such a machine cannot exist. This then implies that a TM that computes $BB$ cannot exist, hence $BB$ is non-computable.

Comment: But is this evidence enough to prove that no TM machine can compute BB(n)? I am asking because this shows that only the proposed TM cannot compute BB(n).

Comment: The argument structure is: Assume there exists a TM that computes $BB(n)$, (the argument), now we have a contradiction. Thus our assumption is wrong. Such a TM cannot exist. Thus $BB(n)$ is non-computable. The TM we chose at the beginning doesn't matter, the only thing relevant is that we assume it computes $BB(n)$ which we use to create a contradiction.